# Scheme's (read) function how do I enter input before the program terminates

Tags: scheme

How do I enter input with scheme's (read) function before the program terminates?
say I have this

```lisp
(define (main)
    (write "Enter K: ")(lambda k (read))
    (write k))
```

I am using the commend mit-scheme to enter the interpreter. When I load the file and call (main) it writes Enter K: then immediately says k is not bound. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you think `(lambda k (read))` will do?

Comment: `(let ((a (read))) (write a))`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `k` is not bound is because the `k` that you're referring to in `(write k)` is not the same as the `k` that you bind in `(lambda k (read))`.

The way that you can see this is that you can see whether the `k` of `(write k)` is inside the parentheses of the lambda expression, which it isn't.

To solve this, you write `(lambda k (write k))`.
When you then apply `(read)` to this lambda expression, `k` is bound to your input.

In total, you can write this as

```
(define (main)
    (write "Enter K: ")
    ((lambda k (write k)) (read))
)
```

Now, there's no reason to define a lambda expression to then immediately evaluate it so you can write this as

```
(define (main)
    (write "Enter K: ")
    (write (read))
)
```

Another problem that you may encounter depending on your interpreter is that stdout is not flushed before stdin, meaning that you will have to write your input before `"Enter K: "` is printed.
You can fix this by flushing stdout by calling `(flush)`.

You might also be interested in using `display` instead of `write` since it will output `Enter K:`  instead of `"Enter K: "`.

This gives you

```
(define (main)
    (display "Enter K: ")
    (flush)
    (write (read))
)
```

Notice that you might not want `display` for the last output, depending on your preferences of course.